# SWIG C++ to R: Cannot naming argument having default C++ values

Tags: c++, r, swig, optional-parameters

Using SWIG C++ to R, I cannot use the name of the arguments when the C++ function has default argument values.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the error (Ubuntu 18, Swig 4.0.2, R 4.2.0, GCC 7.5.0):

**DefArg.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
void print2Values(double a = 1.1, double b = 2.2)
{
  std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

**defarg.i**

```
%module rdefarg

%include DefArg.hpp
%{
  #include "DefArg.hpp"
%}
```

**test_defarg.r**

```
#!/usr/bin/R

dyn.load("rdefarg.so")
source("rdefarg.R")

print2Values()
print2Values(4.4)
print2Values(4.4, 5.5)
print2Values(a=4.4)
print2Values(b=5.5) # This one fails!
```

**make.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Cleanup
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
rm -f *.exe *.o *.so

# Generate SWIG wrapper
swig -c++ -r -o defarg_wrap.cpp defarg.i
# Build rdefarg.so (using R)
g++ -std=c++11 -fpic -shared defarg_wrap.cpp -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -o rdefarg.so
# Execute the R test script
Rscript test_defarg.r
```

**Execution** of make.sh (error message has been translated to english):

```
a = 1.1, b = 2.2
NULL
a = 4.4, b = 2.2
NULL
a = 4.4, b = 5.5
NULL
a = 4.4, b = 2.2
NULL
Error in f(...) : unused argument (b = 5.5)
Calls : print2Values
Execution stopped
```

Have you any idea to help me please?

Comment: Not familiar with R, but FYI generating the wrapper for Python doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Yes I can confirm. This is only related to R target language.